# How to know the all the ranks that are part of a group in MPI outside that group?

Tags: mpi

Is there a way for a rank 'R' to know the processes in a particular MPI_Group 'Grp', despite 'R' not belonging to 'Grp'. I want to do it without using any point to point communication calls, collective communication calls like Gather, Gatherv, Scatter etc and shared memory. Is it possible to use `MPI_Group_translate_ranks` for this purpose?

Comment: What do you really want to do? This is a means to an end.

Comment: I want to have all communicator groups' ranks at node 0.

Comment: Does R have all the group objects of interest? I'd not, communication will be required. In any case, code would be useful here.

Comment: Ok let me put it this way. I was thinking of printing all the ranks of all communicators groups in an output file. For this I was thinking of a way to get access to all the communicator groups from node 0(where I was dumping all information to a file), so that I can get the ranks that are part of all communicator groups. Hope this helps.

Comment: For that, you would be far better off having a rank in the group do the printing, rather than shipping everything to root.

Answer (score 0):

If an MPI process is not in a particular group, then it won't have a handle to be able to query it. In MPI, the only way you get handles to groups, communicators, etc. is to be part of the creation of that handle.

So to answer your question, no, there probably isn't a way to learn information about groups of which you are not a member.

That being said, your question is still rather unclear. You're asking to do something that I haven't ever heard of someone wanting to do before. If you can give a better demonstration of what exactly you're trying to do and why, you might get a better answer with another solution.

Comment: Ok let me put it this way. I was thinking of printing all the ranks of all communicators groups in an output file. For this I was thinking of a way to get access to all the communicator groups from node 0(where I was dumping all information to a file), so that I can get the ranks that are part of all communicator groups. Hope this helps.